# How do I run a SQL Server 2005 job on Windows 7?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have Windows 7 and SQL Server 2005 Version 9.00.1399.

I can successfully create an SSIS Package, however I am unable to execute it successfully as a scheduled job. When I run the job, SQL Agent reports `Unable to start execution of step 1 (reason:Could not get proxy data for proxy_id = 1). The step failed.`

All SQL services are running successfully.

The same kind of activity on Windows Server 2008 R2 Edition and SQL Server 2005 Version 9.00.4035 works successfully.

Does anyone know why this wouldn't work on Windows 7?

Comment: In "Job Properties" ->  "Owner" choose user by pushing button "..." should be like  `DOMAIN\Username` not `Username`. Works?

Comment: It won't hurt to patch your SQL Server version. 1399 is RTM and [SP4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7218) is available. Had an issue with a coworker's SSIS execution yesterday wherein patch corrected the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the major problem is that your username don't have rights.
There are some examples how to create Accounts:

[SSIS run  on different Account](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+%28SSIS%29/69441/)

[SSIS runninng job](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14401/How-to-Schedule-and-Run-a-SSIS-package-DTS-Job-in)

I would try set Owner "yourself" your PC Administrator user.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your updates and help, as improving this solution, I found out the real problem and its actual rectification.

Solution was, we needed to install **Service Pack 3** CD, then this issue got fixed. For the **Windows 7** and **server 2008** operating systems with as like you people referred the above.